# Is JSON a language, if not how would it be classified?

Tags: xml, json, programming-languages

Considering **JSON (JavaScript Object Notation)**, is **JSON** itself a language, or is it only defined in context of another language?  By language, I mean a programming language that might be using JSON to transmit/receive data.

It is interesting that **XML** is not Turing complete, yet has *language* in its name.  Perhaps this implies a broader definition of language for this purpose?

Comment: It's a fuzzy definition. http://stackoverflow.com/q/1325686/139010 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/1775799/139010.

Comment: See also [this interesting discussion](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/314599/why-is-xml-called-a-language-exactly) about why XML is called a language.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's a [data interchange](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronic_data_interchange) format.

> **JSON** (JavaScript Object Notation) is a lightweight data-interchange format.

http://json.org

> JavaScript Object Notation is a text-based open standard designed for human-readable data interchange.
>
> **Type of format:** Data interchange

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Json

---

> is it only defined in context of a language

Certainly not. It is entirely possible to write applications which use JSON but not JavaScript.

Comment: JavaScript was just an example, not trying to call it out in particular.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you were asking there. I can compose a text file with nothing in it but JSON and it's still JSON.

Comment: ...is it only defined in context of a language.  Any language will do, I'm just asking about JSON standing on its own as a language, or if it is perhaps a subset?

Comment: It stands on its own **as a data format.** It is not a language, in the sense that it is not [Turing complete.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness)

Comment: Then again, XML is a "markup language" and is also not Turing complete, and yet has "language" in its name. So **you* need to decide what qualifies as a language for the purposes of this question.

Comment: That is a really good point.  I updated the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

JSON is a data format. It could be classified as a language, but not a programming language.

Its relationship to JavaScript is that it shares its syntax (more or less) with a subset of JavaScript literals. The [JSON specification](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt) defines it completely; it doesn't depend on references to the JavaScript specification.

Answer (score 2):

According to Computer Science, JSON accomplishes the definition of language, so **it is definitely a language** (in the same way XML is).
Is is basically a set of possible strings formed by symbols of an alphabet. It has also syntactic rules.

But **it is not a programming language**. In terms of programming, it is a format or notation.

Answer (score 1):

I would classify it as a format of structured data, not a language. This [Wikipedia article about Turing completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turing_completeness#Data_languages) does a pretty good job summing it up:

> The notion of Turing-completeness does not apply to languages such as XML, HTML, JSON, YAML and S-expressions, because **they are typically used to represent structured data, not describe computation**. These are sometimes referred to as markup languages, or more properly as "container languages" or "data description languages".